# Unable to auth against mongo docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication

I've create a mongo server using the official docker container.

If I inspect the container I find the following expected env:

```
 "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root",
                "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxx",
                "MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=unpubd",
                "affinity:container==5b49b08d73960bfefe10eae7df25328f2296d9eb2c648af330e3ef75f928a289",
                ,
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "JSYAML_VERSION=3.13.1",
                "MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org",
                "MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org",
                "MONGO_MAJOR=5.0",
                "MONGO_VERSION=5.0.4"
            ],
```

My understanding is that this should create a db called unpubd and
a root user with the stated password.

The problem is that I'm unable to auth to the container.
I've tried three different urls all with the same result.:

```
mongodb://root:XXXX@localhost:27017/
mongodb://root:XXXX@localhost:27017/unpub
mongodb://root:XXXX@localhost:27017/admin
mongodb://root:XXXX@localhost:27017/unpubd?authSource=admin

MongoDart Error: Authentication failed.
```

I've also tried the mongo command shell:

```
use admin
var x = new Mongo('localhost');
var mydb = x.getDB('unpubd');
mydb.auth('root', 'XXXX')
Error: Authentication failed.
```

I'm unclear about the auth db vs my unpubd db.
Do I auth with the admin db?
I assume the root user will be able to rw the unpub db?

Here is my docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3.1'

networks:
  unpubd:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodata: null

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db 
    networks:
      - unpubd
    ports:
      - 27017:27017      

    logging:
      driver: "local"

  unpubd:
    container_name: unpubd
    image: noojee/unpubd:latest
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_DATABASE: ${MONGO_DATABASE}
      MONGO_HOST: ${MONGO_HOST}
      MONGO_PORT: ${MONGO_PORT}
      UNPUBD_PORT: ${UNPUBD_PORT}
      TZ: ${TZ}
    links:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - unpubd
    ports:
      - ${UNPUBD_PORT}:${UNPUBD_PORT}
    logging:
      driver: "local"
```

example .env file

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc1234
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=unpubd
MONGO_DATABASE=unpubd
MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc1234
MONGO_DATABASE=unpubd
MONGO_HOST=mongodb
MONGO_PORT=27017
TZ=AUS Eastern Daylight Time
UNPUBD_HOST=0.0.0.0
UNPUBD_PORT=4000
```

Comment: Took down my answer, you are right it seems it is the auth part that is failing. Could you share any minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I've added a sample .env file. Save it into the same directory as the docker-compose.yaml file and run docker-compose up.

Comment: Thanks for adding all the configs needed to repro, I've added another answer and checked that is is actually working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a second to figure this out.

From the logs I can see that when the mongodb starts it does this:

```
mongo   | Successfully added user: {
mongo   |   "user" : "root",
mongo   |   "roles" : [
mongo   |       {
mongo   |           "role" : "root",
mongo   |           "db" : "admin"
mongo   |       }
mongo   |   ]
mongo   | }
```

As you can see, it creates the user in the admin db, not in the one you specify in the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`.

Looking at the documentation for the mongo image on docker hub:

> `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`, `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`:
>
> These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's password. This user is created in the admin authentication database and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

and

> `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`:
>
> This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used for creation scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js

What you need to do to make it work is create a script to add your user to the database that you use in the init env variable, something like:

```
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "root",
     pwd: "abc1234",
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
   }
)
```

and bind it to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

Comment: I have a script but I can't see any evidence in the logs that it is being ran and the auth still fails.

Comment: did you delete the volume before running docker compose up?

Comment: When the script is ran, you should see the log entry similar to this: `mongo   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/<your_script.js>`

Comment: I thought I had but there was a bug  in my reset script :<. Fixed that and its now working :D. Appreciate all the help. If you are ever in Melbourne Australia I owe you a beer.